# DMZ (Portforwarding) in OpenVPN

Tags: networking, server, openvpn, port-forwarding

I am running an self-hosted openvpn server with few clients. I want to expose 1 client to the external network, how can I do that? I see similar option in paid admin panel, but I'm using the free version which offers only a command line interface (CLI). If the complete exposure of a client is not possible, then I want to forward the ports without manually changing iptables each and every time.

Current structure is something like that:

```
+------------+
|            |
|  Client 1  +--------------------+
|            |                    |                +----------------------+
+------------+                    v                |                      |
                               Internet <---------->   Self-Hosted        |
+------------+                    ^                |   OpenVPN Server     |
|            |                    |                |   Community Edition  |
|  Client 2  +--------------------+                |                      |
|            |                                     +----------------------+
+------------+
```

Now I want to expose the client 2 to the public network (internet) through the VPN server. I can do that manually exposing ports using IP tables. But if a new port need a new rule in IP table, which I have to put manually. I am not very proficient with IP tables or openvpn administration, also exposing port manually is not effective enough (though may good for security perspective).

I want to expose the client 2 through the vpn server for once and all. How can I achieve that goal?

Note: I had posted it in https://superuser.com/questions/1434150/dmz-portforwarding-in-openvpn but no luck :(

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with openvpn, but with how the kernel does IP forwarding. You'll have to use `iptables` or a front end for forwarding packets. The paid OpenVPN product probably wraps this in a web UI.

Comment: yes, but I can forward port manually one by one. I am unable to expose a host completely without specifying each and every port.

Comment: You may want to forward a [range of ports](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-iptables-multiport-range/).

Comment: @vidarlo that's a good idea, though I was looking for a way to do it dynamically or with least amount of user interaction. As, the ports will be open for short period type and port numbers are random (not predefined). More like making the VPN server transparent from public view and showing an internal server as a front.

Comment: I think you should describe your use case in some more details, because it's not clear to me what you want to do.